# Decompile apk using the keystore that signed it

Tags: android

Me and my colleague are writing and android app and we are using git to track code changes.
After the last pull on my side, i changed many lines of code and inserted a lot of new ones.

While trying to push the changes, there were some conflicts and i got his version of the project and mine was gone.

"Fortunately", i have the newest version of the application installed on my phone and the keystore used to sign it on my pc.

**Is there any way to decompile an .apk file using the keystore that signed it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, no.  While it is possible to decompile an apk, the process will produce something ugly enough that the time taken to recover it will probably be prohibitive.  You can use baksamali [(link)](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) to disassemble it, along with similar tools to decompile from .class files to Java files.  Unfortunately, however, the compilation process loses enough context that you will have probably lost a lot of structure in your files, and the result you get won't be workable without a lot of smoothing over.  In this instance, while it is *technically* possible, the amount of time that it will probably take to reverse engineer the produced decompiled code will be high enough that you'd rather probably just redo the coding yourself..

Comment: This is great and definitely not the answer i was hoping for. Just in case someone has a better solution, I'll wait some time before accepting your answer.

Comment: This is the same as any decompilation process: the compiler throws away all of your comments, temporary variable names, inlines things (sometimes, I don't think the java compiler does this), and in general hoping to get things back from decompilation is a real pain, which is particularly useful as otherwise software piracy would be much more prevalent

Comment: I understand, but when i leave my house and lock the door i expect to be able to unlock it when i'm back.

Comment: Then compiling your code is more like selling your house to someone and hoping they won't change the locks.